# add data collection component sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, data-warehouse, sql-server-2008-express, warehouse

**I have been searching for hours, and I can't find a way to add data collection component in object explorer , 
ps: I'm using  sql server 2008 r2**

Comment: From [this link](http://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-performance-monitoring-data-collector-part-2-set-up-and-usage/): *Data Collector is supported only in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 and higher, in the **Enterprise, Standard, Business Intelligence, and Web editions**. SQL Server Integration Services must be installed*. You have the express edition? In that case, it is not supported.

Comment: yup I'm using the express edition,  thanks anyway  :)